# Postgresql, JPA, primary key

Tags: database, postgresql, jpa

I have a problem with Postgresql + JPA and auto-incrementing key that I just doesnt get solved. I googled half of the day, but nothing works.

On the Web I found the following solution

```
@Entity(name="FAST_FEATURE")
@SequenceGenerator(name="scanIdGen", initialValue=1000,     
 sequenceName="scan_seq", allocationSize=1)
 public class FastFeature implements Serializable 
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="FAST_FEATURE_id_seq",
                   sequenceName="FAST_FEATURE_id_seq",
                   allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                generator="FAST_FEATURE_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable=false)
    private Long id=null;
    ....
}
```

Later on I try to persist the entity inside an EJB with:

```
@Stateless
public class FastRestService {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="FastSearchServerPU")
EntityManager em;

@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;
...

 @POST
 @Path("/feature")
 public Response createFeature(ServerFeature serverFeature)
 {
   ....
    FastFeature fastFeature=new FastFeature();
    ...
    em.persist(fastFeature);

 }
```

If I run it I always get the error message:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] 
(Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.qualifier):     
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: doppelter 
Schlüsselwert verletzt Unique-Constraint „fast_feature_pkey“ 
(double key value violates unique-constraint)
 Detail: Schlüssel „(id)=(1)“ existiert bereits.
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO FAST_FEATURE (id, DOES_EXIST, HARD_CONSTRAINT, NAME,     
FAST_FEATURE_SET_ID, FAST_FEATURE_TYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(ch.hslu.mse.fasttrack.model.FastFeature[ id=1 ])
    at     
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:745)
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:275)
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:170)
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:721)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:505)
```

Would be thankful for any remark.

Tim

Comment: Do you set the id yourself by any chance?

Comment: i just debugged my code. Just before calling persist(), the id is still null. After the persist command it is changed to 2, but an entry with id 2 already exists in the database.

Comment: Use Identity sequence generation with Postgres.

Comment: meanwhile i found out that the sequence is created in the postgres database but not the connection between sequence and id

Comment: fast_search=> SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind='S';
       relname
---------------------
 fast_feature_id_seq
(1 Zeile)

fast_search=> SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('fast_feature','id')